# Show that $|\{\omega \mid \mathbb P\{\omega \}\geq \frac{1}{n}\}|\leq n$

Tags: probability

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space. How can I show that show that $$\left|\left\{\omega \mid \mathbb P\{\omega \}\geq \frac{1}{n}\right\}\right|\leq n\ \ ?$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Suppose it has at least $n+1$ elements $\omega _1,...,\omega _{n+1}$. What can you say about $$\mathbb P\{\omega _1,...,\omega _{n+1}\}\ \ ?$$